# Sending XACML request with SAML Binding with profile { Spring security taking WSO2 as IDP }

Tags: spring, spring-security, wso2, saml, xacml

Hi I have developed Service Providers for implementing SAML WebSSO in OpenAM and WSO2, my requirement is to implement XACML with SAML, so I have tried to look at the profiles available for which i can modify my auth request,

I had used this profile

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol:wd-13
```

and added this value in samlEntryPoint present in securityContext.xml :

```
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol" />
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After running the program i am getting exception like this :

```
rg.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: User specified binding urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:profile:saml2.0:v2:schema:protocol is not supported by the IDP using profile urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:SSO:browser
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.getSingleSignOnService(WebSSOProfileImpl.java:147)
at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl.sendAuthenticationRequest(WebSSOProfileImpl.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.initializeSSO(SAMLEntryPoint.java:226)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.commence(SAMLEntryPoint.java:153)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help for what can i do to fix it, plus if there is any other approach for modifying the auth request so as to get the authentication request modified for both xacml and saml request.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by implementing XACML with SAML?

Comment: @farasath he is referring to the SAML profile of XACML whereby you can send a XACML request to a PDP via a SAML binding

Comment: okay. I think http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2012/02/implementing-saml-to-xacml.html seems to have some info related to this

Comment: thanks @farasath i have seen that link before and that is exactly which i want, for which i have been following this [https://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/2.0/access_control-xacml-2.0-saml-profile-spec-os.pdf ] , but i need help on implementing it, as I have tried to use the error but got the issue of the exception which i showed above